# Could not start rails server on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I can't start my rails app after installing Ubuntu 20.04

There is [traceback](https://pastebin.com/wr79CAi5).

Also, I have the same errors:

`...rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so: warning: already initialized constant Etc::...`

then I've checked my rails version.

After reinstall my OS via erase, I have restored my backup of `/home` from `Ubuntu 18.04`
and checked my version of `ruby` `rails` and `nodejs`. `Ruby` and `rails` were the same, but I have to install `nodejs` and some `postgres` packages. Now, after that I've tried to run `rails s` in my project folder and there errors from traceback were appeared. Also, the command

`yarn install --check-files`

can't finish successfully, cause

`info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...` error.

What should I do to start my app successfully?

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

gem "rails_12factor"
# gem "hashid-rails", "~> 1.0"
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'pry'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
end

gem 'minitest-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem "active_model_serializers"
```

Ruby: `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]`

Rails: `Rails 6.0.2.2`

Nodejs: `v10.19.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
run `gem uninstall etc`
```

and then `gem update etc --default`

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it's not woriking. Yep, now ```already initialized constant``` errors are gone, but other errors are stay

Answer (score 0):

Okey, after post of @Bodh1004 I have an idea to do the same action with `ffi` gem, and this is works! Thanks for the idea!
Anyway, i have the same `already initialized constant` errors:

```
/home/procy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:116: warning: already initialized constant Forwardable::VERSION
/home/procy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/forwardable-1.3.1/lib/forwardable/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/home/procy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:117: warning: already initialized constant Forwardable::FORWARDABLE_VERSION
/home/procy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/forwardable-1.3.1/lib/forwardable/version.rb:4: warning: previous definition of FORWARDABLE_VERSION was here
```

I'll try to solve them.

Comment: I had the same with ruby 2.6.8. `gem uninstall forwardable`  made them go away

Answer (score 0):

Remove `yarn.lock` and log errors 
And repeat